# How to fix parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I wrote the following code and put the error in the title.
Can someone help me please?
Error in line 7

```
punkteImKreis :: Double -> [(Double, Double)]
punkteImKreis k = [(x,y)|x <- [1.0,2.0..k-1.0],
                         y <- [1.0,2.0..k-1.0] ]

anteilImKreis :: Double -> Double
let l = length(punkteImKreis)
in anteilImKreis k = (fromIntegral (l)) / k^2
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @moonGoose They have written the error in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in this definition:

```
anteilImKreis :: Double -> Double
let l = length(punkteImKreis)
in anteilImKreis k = (fromIntegral (l)) / k^2
```

`let` is an expression; therefore, it has to be *inside* a definition (that is, on the *right* of an `=` sign). This should be:

```
anteilImKreis :: Double -> Double
anteilImKreis k =
  let l = length(punkteImKreis)
  in (fromIntegral (l)) / k^2
```

By the way, you don't really need parentheses around an argument of a function when it's just one identifier. I would rewrite this as follows:

```
anteilImKreis :: Double -> Double
anteilImKreis k =
  let l = length punkteImKreis
  in (fromIntegral l) / k^2
```

Additionally, this exposes another error. `punkteImKreis` isn't a list; it's a function which *returns* a list, which means you can't directly take its `length`. I would assume you meant the following:

```
anteilImKreis :: Double -> Double
anteilImKreis k =
  let l = length (punkteImKreis k)
  in (fromIntegral l) / k^2
```

Comment: Minor notes: the parentheses around `fromIntegral l` are also redundant, and this can be written with a `where` block `anteilImKreis k = fromIntegral l / k ^ 2 where l = length (punkteImKreis k)` or without local bindings `anteilImKreis k = fromIntegral (length (punkteImKreis k)) / k ^ 2`

Comment: @JonPurdy I know the brackets around `fromIntegral l` are redundant, but personally I prefer to write it this way to avoid ambiguity. I'm also aware that it can be written using `where` or without bindings, but I thought that doing this would be irrelevant to answering the question.

Comment: @bradm: Of course, just some addenda for OP and beginner Haskellers coming across this in the future.